# Get indexPath in editActionsForRowAtIndexPath: and use it elsewhere?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swipe, nsindexpath

How can I get the `indexPath` from `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:` and use the variable in a separate method (`addSpeciesToFavoriteForCell`)?

```
// Swipe to left for favorite

- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewRowAction *favAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault
                                                                         title:@"Favorite"
                                                                       handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
                                                                           UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                                                                           [self tableView:tableView addSpeciesToFavoriteForCell:cell];
                                                                           self.tableView.editing = NO;
                                                                       }];
    favAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];//color of favorite
    return @[favAction];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView addSpeciesToFavoriteForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
    UILabel *comNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    NSFetchRequest *findExisting = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [findExisting setEntity:
     [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favorite" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedOjbectContext]];
    [findExisting setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",comNameLabel.text]];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matchedRecords = [self.managedOjbectContext executeFetchRequest:findExisting error:&error];
    if ([matchedRecords count]!=0)  return;

    Favorite *favEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favorite" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedOjbectContext];
    favEntity.type = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    favEntity.name = comNameLabel.text;

    if (![self.managedOjbectContext save:&error]) {
        //NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        abort();
    }     
}
```

Comment: Why not simply pass the index path to the method rather than the cell?? And the `tableview` parameter is not needed either since it's a property in that class.

Comment: i do that vadian.thank.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `indexPath` from cell something like in `addSpeciesToFavoriteForCell`,

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView addSpeciesToFavoriteForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
  {
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

       // other code 
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an instance variable (NSIndexPath) and set it in editActionsForRowAtIndexPath.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *index;


- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

index = indexPath;

UITableViewRowAction *favAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault
                                                                     title:@"Favorite"
                                                                   handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
                                                                       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                                                                       [self tableView:tableView addSpeciesToFavoriteForCell:cell];
                                                                       self.tableView.editing = NO;
                                                                   }];
favAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];//color of favorite
return @[favAction];
}
```